# Does express app.use execute every time a path is heard on server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my server.js file, where I may have many lines of code that use `app.use`, do these lines `app.use` execute every time a path is hit? I am a little confused on how this works when using the express router. If I have something like

```
var example1 = require('./js/exampleRoutes.js)
var example2 = require('./js/example2Routes.js)

app.use(express.static(process.cwd() + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

app.use(example1, example2);

app.listen(PORT);
```

Do all four lines of app.use execute everytime a path is hit, and depending on the path hit, it will redirect the program to either example1 routes or example2 routes?

exampleRoutes.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
    ....
});
```

example2Routes.js

```
router.post('/create', function(req, res){
    ....
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does express app.use execute every time a path is heard on server.js

It depends upon whether you're using a path with any of your `app.use()` statements and it depends upon whether all the `app.use()` statements pass control onto the next handler or whether some of them purposely terminate the chain and handle the final response themselves.

All `app.use()` statements are registered as middleware handlers for all requests that hit that `app` object.  If it has a specific path on it, then it will only be called if it matches that path.  If it does not have a path (as in your examples), then it will be considered for every request.

When a given middleware handler is called, it is passed three arguments as in this example from the Express doc:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: %d', Date.now());
  next();
});
```

Note, that last argument `next`.  When a middleware function gets called, it has three main choices for how it's going to work:

1. It can do something and then let the request continue on to other handlers.
2. It can do something and then trigger an error (for example authentication failed or a require session cookie is missing).
3. It can do something and then send the final response (`res.send(xxxx)`) and not pass control on to other handlers.

The mechanism for passing control on to other handlers is by calling `next()` when you are done with your processing and ready for other handlers to get their crack at this request.  If each middleware handler calls `next()` for each request they see, then ALL the `app.use()` handlers will get called for every single request.  In the example above from the Express doc, you can see that this is a very simple middleware handler.  All it does is log the time of the request and then it calls `next()` to pass control onto the next handler in the chain.

If one of the middleware handler does not call `next()`, then for that request, none of the handlers that come after it in the chain will get called for that request.

---

On a separate note, you can limit middleware to certain url paths only.  Rather than calling

```
app.use(example1)
```

you can include a path as an argument such as:

```
app.use('/api', example1);
```

Then, this middleware will only be called for paths that start with `/api`.

Or, you can similarly use Routers to create branches of middleware.  For example, if you have some middleware handlers that you only want to be called for requests that start with `/api`, then you can create a router for the `/api` prefix on the URL and attach the middleware handlers to that router instead of to the app object and then the middleware handlers on that router will only be called for requests that start with `/api` and are thus directed to that router.

```
// create api router
var router = express.Router();

// register middleware that is called only when requests go through this router
router.use(example1);

// register normal get handler
router.get('/whatever', function(req, res) {...});

// hook api router into the app
app.use('/api', router);
```